# Silverlight binding in nested usercontrols

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a user control that has its own view model. I have added an instance of this view model as data context to the control. It works fine, but I need to bind some controls in this user control to the parents datacontext. In other words, I need to bind the parent controls data context to the child controls view model. Need some suggestion on how proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to use Ancestor Binding to find the DataContext you want.

For example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=myParentControlType}}" />
```

You could also target an element by name:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, ElementName=myParentCtrl}" />
```